# How to add a domain-switching selector to International Google sites?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, greasemonkey, html-select

I am writing a Greasemonkey script to change the top-level domains of google.com.

The complete code is below. Testing my code in the dev tool, it did display the choosebox and the button. But, when I clicked the button, the page just reloaded, it did not switch language sites.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       GoogleFieldExpress
// @namespace  http://example.gg/
// @version    1.0
// @description  to change field from database
// @match      http://www.google.*/
// @match      https:/www.google.*/
// @copyright  2013,Matthew
// ==/UserScript==

//database domains and varibles
var domains=new Array;
domains=["gg","jp"];
var current="";
if (typeof this.href === "undefined") {
    current = document.location.toString().toLowerCase();
}
else {
   current = this.href.toString().toLowerCase();
}
var inner='\
    <center>\
    <strong>\
        Choose field below: <br />\
    </strong>\
    <form id="choose" >\
    <select id="select_item">'
for (var i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
    inner+='<option value="'+domains[i]+'"\\>'+domains[i]+'</option>';
};


inner+='</select>\
    <button id="goto2">go!</button>\
    </form>\
    </center>\
'

//functions
function getLanguageElement(){
    var lang=document.getElementById("als");
    return lang;
}
function appendHTML(element,html){
    element.innerHTML+=html;
}
//main process
(function(){
appendHTML(getLanguageElement(),inner);
document.getElementById("goto2").addEventListener("click",function(){windows.location=new String('www.google.')+(document.getElementById("select_item").value)},false);
})();
```

I am a greenhand and really mad at these.
How I can redirect to the right domain and what's wrong with my code?

I want to jump from [www.google.com](http://www.google.com/) to [www.google.gg](http://www.google.gg/) or [www.google.jp](http://www.google.jp/) and so on.

P.S. the "als" element is the container of this sentence "Google.gg offered in: languages"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues:

1. `http://www.google.*/` and `https:/www.google.*/` are [invalid values for `@match`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).  Use:

   ```
   // @include    http://www.google.*/
   // @include    https://www.google.*/
   ```
2. `jp` appears to be an invalid domain.  Google appears to use `co.jp`.
3. `windows` is not a valid object or variable.
4. By using a `<form>` and a `<button>` with the default type, clicking "go!" actually submits the form!  This overrides trying to set the location URL.
5. You need the protocol (http:, etc.) when setting a `location.`
6. Do not use `this` in the global scope of a userscript.  `this` will vary markedly depending on: the browser, the sandbox state, possible the iframe state, etc.  Use `this` only inside functions and only when you are sure what it will refer to.
7. The script needs error checking since the sought nodes will not be present on most Google pages.

There are several more minor issues -- which I'll skip, since Stack Overflow is not really a code-review site.  Just see the working script, below, and note where it is different from the question's script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       GoogleFieldExpress
// @namespace  http://example.gg/
// @version    1.0
// @description  to change field from database
// @include    http://www.google.*/
// @include    https://www.google.*/
// ==/UserScript==
//database domains and variables
var domains = ["gg", "co.jp"];
var current = location.host;  // or location.href. Case-sensitive for a reason
var inner   = '\
    <center>\
    <strong>\
        Choose field below: <br />\
    </strong>\
    <form id="gmChoose">\
    <select id="gmSelect_item">'
;

domains.forEach ( function (item) {
    inner  += '<option value="' + item + '"\\>' + item + '</option>';
} );

inner      += '</select>\
    <button id="gmGoto2" type="button">go!</button>\
    </form>\
    </center>\
';

//main code
var lang = document.getElementById ("als");
if (lang) {
    lang.innerHTML += inner;

    document.getElementById ("gmGoto2").addEventListener ("click", function () {
        location.assign (
            location.protocol + '\/\/www.google.'
            + document.getElementById ("gmSelect_item").value
            + '\/'
        );
    }, false);
}
```